# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType' return length

Tags: python, django

My view method accept values and call score methods, but my terminal output this error >

```
return sum(item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values())
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

**views.py**

```
def cart_update(request):
    cart = Cart(request)

    quantity = request.GET.get('quantity')
    product_slug = request.GET.get('product_slug')

    product = Product.objects.get(slug=product_slug)
    cart.add(product=product, quantity=quantity, update_quantity=True)

    return JsonResponse({ # here errors
        'cart_length':cart.get_length(),
        'cart_total':cart.get_total_price(), 
        'cart_price':cart.get_price(product=product, quantity=quantity)
    })
```

**cart.py**

```
def get_total_price(self):
    return sum(Decimal(item['price']) * item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values())

def get_price(self, product, quantity):
    return quantity * Decimal(product.price)

def get_length(self):
    return sum(item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values())
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: For some of your `item['quantity']`s are `None`, in the `sum(item['quantity'] for ...)` it performs addition "behind" the curtains, and it is possible that your `'quantity'` key maps to `None`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Behind the curtains, the `sum(..)` will call the `+` operator to calculate the sum of the items.

If one of the `item['quantity']`s is `None`, then of course a situation unfolds where you add an `int` with `None`, hence the error.

You can fix it, by filtering for `None` (and zero for example) with:

```
sum(filter(None, (item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values())))
```

Although it is probably beneficial to look *why* there is a `None` in of these dictionaries, and thus prevent that the dictionaries are "contaminated" by `None`s.

Comment: You'd be better off filtering the queryset but as you say in the last sentence, this still will most likely give incorrect data

Answer (score 1):

`self.cart.values()` has some elements in which quantity is `None`

You can sum only items wich don't have a `None` quantity using an `if` statement

```
return sum(item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values() if item['quantity'])
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense, you'd filter the queryset if anything but that would result in most likely incorrect data